# Configuration of I2C bus over a switch in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, kernel-module, device-tree

I have the following simplified schematic for my system.

```
                                   GPIO4
                     +-----------------------------+
                     |             GPIO3           |
                     |  +------------------------+ |
                     |  |          GPIO2         | |
                     |  |  +-------------------+ | |
                     |  |  |       GPIO1       | | |
                     |  |  |  +--------------+ | | |
                     |  |  |  |              | | | |
                   +-+--+--+--+-+            | | | |
I2C1 +-------------+            |            | | | |
                   |            |           ++-+-+-++
I2C2 +-------------+            |    I2C    |       |
                   |   SWITCH   +-----------+  CPU  |
I2C3 +-------------+            |           |       |
                   |            |           +-------+
I2C4 +-------------+            |
                   +------------+
```

What is the best way to implement/configure this in Linux and why? Is it possible to somehow just configure this in the device tree exporting 4 i2c devices in the user-space and whenever someone wants to write/read to one of those 4 i2c buses the corresponding GPIO is asserted?

Is it only possible to be implemented in a kernel module/driver?

Comment: The correct way is to implement it in the kernel with help of the i2c switch driver and 1-4 drivers for slaves (depends how many of them are different). User space drivers for i2c slaves are solely for prototyping.

Comment: There is an "i2c-mux-gpio" driver which should help with this.

Comment: @IanAbbott You are perfectly right, exactly what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

There is an "i2c-mux-gpio" driver which should help with this. – @Ian Abbott Sep 12 '19 at 11:35